# How can I create partition for the following schema?

Tags: mysql

I have a table having 5000 rows every year. I want to make some dynamic partitions to increase the performance.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `purchaser_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bill_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bill_date` date NOT NULL,
  `due_date` date NOT NULL,
  `bill_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `financial_year` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `is_paid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `paid_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ledger_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ledger_type` (`ledger_type`),
  KEY `created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `modified_by` (`modified_by`),
  KEY `supplier_id` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `purchaser_id` (`purchaser_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bills_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ledger_type`) REFERENCES `ledger_types` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bills_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bills_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`modified_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bills_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bills_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`purchaser_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=810 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I expect partitions based on `supplier_id`, `purchaser_id` and `financial_year` columns. Or some other better way.

Comment: if you want dynamic partitions to increase the performance than best to choose financial_year  and hash partition

Comment: A little off topic, but I would not expect any performance improvement from a table with only about 5,000 rows in each partition, or even 50,000. If you experience slow queries I would start by checking for lacking or inadequate indexing and in general focus on query optimization before partitioning. EXPLAIN is a very useful in this context.